# How to display the state and city name from the database on edit page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I am fetching data from the database in the edit page.

I am using CodeIgniter, I have two view pages, `register`, and `edit_register`.

I don't have any issue on `register` page but still, I am sharing the process to understand my issue. On this page country, state, city dependancy is also working. I mean I choose "India" then It will display all state name in state dropdown. Now I choose "Maharashtra" then I choose "Mumbai". Working perfectly.

I submitted the form and in the database, I am getting the value like

```
 Country_name | state_name | city
 101          |  22        | 2707
--------------------------------------
    101-India
    22-Maharashtra
    2707-Mumbai
```

Let's talk about `edit_register` page.

Now I am on the `edit_register` page, I am fetching the country name in the dropdown. I am getting the correct output "India" but I am not getting the state and city name.

So my issue is how to display the state and city name from the database?

Please check this when I click on edit button then I am getting only the country name but state name not displaying.

[image]

If I choose other country and again choose India then I am getting all the state name in the drop-down.

**Controller**

It's displaying my edit page with country name in the drop-down

```
public function search_with_number(){
  $c_mobileno=$this->input->post('c_mobileno_search');
  $got_customer_info['search_customer_info']=$this->Customer_model->get_customer_info($c_mobileno);
  $got_customer_info['get_country']=$this->Customer_model->get_country();// all country name
  $this->load->view('customer/search_order',$got_customer_info);
}
```

**Country drop-down** It's working.

```
<select  class="form_control country_change" name="c_s_country" data-target="target_state_dropdown2">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Country</option>
    <?php foreach ($get_country as $row) {?>
    <option <?php if($row->id == $post->c_s_country ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->country_name;?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

**State drop-down** It's not working

```
<select  class="form_control state_get" name="c_s_state" id="target_state_dropdown2" data-target="city_dropdown2">
    <option value='' disabled selected>Select state</option>
    <!--What code I have to user here-->
</select>
```

**City** It's not working

```
<select  class="form_control city_get" name="c_s_city" id="city_dropdown2">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select city </option>
    <!--What code I have to user here-->
</select>
```

Ajax which I am using in register page

```
    /*Get all the state name using country code*/
   $(".country_change").on('change',function(){
      var country_id=$(this).val();
      var select_list = $(this).data('target'); // The dropdown ID
  $.ajax({
      url:baseUrl +"/Customer_control/statename",
      method:"POST",
      data:"country_id="+country_id,
     dataType: "json",
      success:function(data){
        $('#'+select_list).empty();
        var placeholder="<option value='' disabled selected>Select state</option>";
        $('#'+select_list).html(placeholder);
            $.each(data, function(i, data) {
          $('#'+select_list).append("<option value='" + data.id + "'>" + data.state_name + "</option>");
            });
      }
     });
  });
   /*Get all the city name using state code*/
   $(".state_get").on('change',function(){
      var state_id=$(this).val();
      var select_list = $(this).data('target'); // The dropdown ID
  $.ajax({
      url:baseUrl +"/Customer_control/cityname",
      method:"POST",
      data:"state_id="+state_id,
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(data){
        $('#'+select_list).empty();
        var placeholder="<option value='' disabled selected>Select city</option><option value='Other'>Other</option>";
        $('#'+select_list).html(placeholder);
        $.each(data, function(i, data) {
        $('#'+select_list).append("<option value='" + data.id + "'>" + data.cities_name + "</option>");
            });
      }

     });
  });
```

**State model**

```
   public function get_country()
{
  $get_country = array('is_country_active' => 1);
    $this->db->where($get_country);
     $query = $this->db->get('countries');
      $result = $query->result();
      if($result)
      {
        return $result;
      }
      else 
      {
        return 0;
      } 
}

public function get_state($country_id){
  $get_state = array('is_state_active' => 1,'country_id'=>$country_id);
    $this->db->where($get_state);
     $query = $this->db->get('states');
      $result = $query->result();
      if($result)
      {
        return $result;
      }
      else 
      {
        return 0;
      } 
}
public function get_city($state_id){
  $get_city = array('is_city_active' => 1,'state_id'=>$state_id);
    $this->db->where($get_city);
     $query = $this->db->get('cities');
      $result = $query->result();
      if($result)
      {
        return $result;
      }
      else 
      {
        return 0;
      } 
}
```

I haven't added the city JS.

Now Please check my Ajax code, My state name is changing when I select a country name.  I have to display the state and city  name onload from the database

Comment: Does your `$this->Customer_model->get_country();` return the state and city which user had posted while registering?

Comment: @Nik, Thanks for the reply, Yes, While registering I am getting all the country name. That's return on country name only

Comment: OK. So are you missing out to select the User's preferred city and state? Where are you fetching the registered user's city and state? Like you have `Customer_model->get_country();` for fetching country right?

Comment: Do you mean the states are not displayed on initial page load, or not displayed when you change country?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, There is no issue while register, country and state and city dependancy are working and able to submit the data in the database.  Now What I am doing is, I am on the edit page. I am fetching the data from the database. I am getting the country name but not getting the state and city name.

Comment: Yes - I am asking if states are missing *on initial page load* or *when changing country*?  In other words, when you first visit the edit page, do you see states correctly before changing anything?

Comment: I was assuming that the `edit` page is editing something, so a country should be already selected, and so states for that country already shown.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: No, I am not getting the state name because I haven't added the PHP code. if you notice in my question I haven't added. I added php code in the  country dropdown. Not getting the idea what to add for state name

Comment: @Don'tPanic, Yes, you are right. for the country. Now what code I have to use for the state name? Should I use other AJAX code?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, Have you understood my issue? or should I explain in details?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use the same code you use for the country to get the state as well(with different selection of course). Just fetch the state from the database. If i understood your code correctly you have already stored the state name in the database.

Comment: @nikosfotiadis, I am using the same code. The script I added in the question that I am using for the register as well as edit.

Comment: Now What I found, I change the country name from drop-down then I am getting all the state name in the drop-down. but why onload not getting? I mean I register country, state name, city from register page. Now I want to edit the state name but I am not getting the state name onload because I haven't added the PHP code. I need to know what code I have to use. Please check my code in the question.

Comment: @user9437856 Are you trying to get the states based on the selected country when you load the page? If this is the case maybe the country isn't set yet since you do both at the onload of the page.

Comment: @nikosfotiadis, I think there are lots of miss communication. I will again explain to you in detail.

Comment: Register page:- I have the country, state, city name in the dropdown. All are the depend on each other. If I choose any country name than It will display the sate name accounting to country name same as on city.  for example I choose India, Maharashtra, Mumbai.
and submitted the form. Now I have to edit the registered information. So I am on edit page and I am fetching all the information on the edit page. There I am getting an only country name. I am not getting the state name and city name.

Comment: It should be:
$got_customer_info['get_city']=$this->Customer_model->get_state();
in the search_with_number() function. And then:
<?php foreach ($get_state as $row) {?>
   <option <?php if($row->id == $post->c_s_state ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } 
   ?> value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->state_name;?> 
  </option>
<?php }?>
at: " <!--What code I have to user here-->"
Same goes for the city. Of course the names for your functions can be different.

Comment: @nikosfotiadis, Yes, I don't have a PHP code in the state name I already added in the question the "<!--What code I have to the user here-->".

Comment: @user9437856 sorry for previous comment, i hit enter by mistake and posted it unfished.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180101/discussion-between-user9437856-and-nikos-fotiadis).

Answer (score 0):

In edit view, you need to do the same as you did for country. First of all, you need to fetch all your state and city from db.
Also you need to store state_id and city_id in db if you are not storing it during creation.

Now you need to pass those data to your edit view and do the same as you did for the country like this:-

```
<select name = "state">
<option value="">Choose State</option>  
    <?php foreach($state as $row){ ?> 
          <option value="<?php echo $row->state_id; ?>"  <?php if($row->state_id == $selected->state_id){  echo "SELECTED";}  ?>> <?php echo $row->state_id; ?></option>  
    <?php } ?>    
</select>
```

Do the same thing for city also. Please also remember you need to execute ajax at edit page also if the user changes the city.

This should be the code on the controller:-

```
public function search_with_number(){
  $c_mobileno=$this->input->post('c_mobileno_search');
  $got_customer_info['search_customer_info']=$this->Customer_model- 
   >get_customer_info($c_mobileno); //get here your saved state id of this user and match it in the view level
  $got_customer_info['get_country']=$this->Customer_model->get_country();// all country name;
  $got_customer_info['get_state']=$this->State_model->get_state();// all state name;
  $this->load->view('customer/search_order',$got_customer_info);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Varun. I added the State model code to get the state name. I am using the same model script in register page. Should I use other State model code for this?

Comment: No need to use other State model but you need to get that particular state id which the user selected at time of creation of his record. After getting that record,match that state id with all your states as you have already done for your country.

Comment: @VarunKumar, I am getting the particular state id. my get_state function is not working because of I passed county id.

Comment: Your get_state function will only wok if you change the country from drop-down. Here at this function you need to add these lines :-      

 `public function search_with_number(){    

  $got_customer_info['get_selected_state']=$this->Customer_model->get_customer_info($c_id); //get that id of state which user selected at creation    

  $got_customer_info['get_state']=$this->Customer_model->get_state();// all state name
}`

Comment: Ye, You are right if I change the country name from the drop-down that get_state function will work but I have to write a new function for $this->Customer_model->get_state(); right?

Comment: Yes for getting all states you have to write a new function. Other than that, you need not to write anything new. You can use all your currently existing function.

Comment: @VarunKumar, Can you help me with existing code? Can you share the code with me?

Comment: I have updated the code by adding the method from where you were passing data. Please look into that and do read all the comments also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Give me some time to implement this.. I will reply you soon.